# Wedge's pick_event handler is not called

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

I have the below code to display a wedge, and I would like to do something once a user clicks on the patch. Therefore I connected a handler to the `"pick_event"` and I made enabled picking the patch by passing the `picker=True` keyword arg.

All is fine, except when I actually click on the patch nothing happens, i.e. the handler seems to not get called.

Can anyone reproduce the issue or propose a fix?

```
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

patches = [Wedge((5., 5.), 0.5, 30., 330., picker=True)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches))
ax.set_xlim([0, 10.])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10.])

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', lambda evt: print(evt))

plt.show()
```

When I add another `ax.scatter([2.5], [2.5], picker=True)` and click on that point instead, the handler is properly called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `set_picker` function of the PatchCollection. I didn't try but I found something of that sort in the documentation. 
[set_picker documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/collections_api.html?highlight=picker#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection.set_picker)

Comment: Yes, or just put `picker=True` into the collection instead of the Wedge.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `picker=True` to the `PatchCollection` works.